# ui:inputDate how to add error style

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I have a component with ui:inputDate when the changes 
I'm trying to validate that there is a value and add error border.

```
dateInputReference.set("v.errors",[{message:'missing data'}]);
$A.util.addClass(dateInputReference, "sld-has-error");
```

This adds the error message to the date input and the styling to the html  element. To get the red border I need to add the styling to the enclosing div. How can I do it?

Comment: I think the class name is `slds-has-error` not `sld-has-error`

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like below :-

```
<div style="{!v.errors != null ? 'border-style: solid;
    border-color:red': ''">
```